# Vent filter for floor intake grille?

Tags: heating, filter

I have an intake on the floor, it's 6x30 and I can't seem to find a vent filter for it.  I know there's a filter down inside the heater but I am trying to prevent pet hair from entering the duct and I can't seem to find one.  Is there filters for floor mounted intakes that I can put into the vent grille?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look for cut to fit foam filter for a window air conditioner.  It's roughly 1/4" thick very lightweight foam so it doesn't reduce airflow very much, but it'll catch most pet fur.

Comment: This looks like what I was after thanks.